# Error in scipy sparse diags matrix construction

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

When using scipy.sparse.spdiags or scipy.sparse.diags I have noticed want I consider to be a bug in the routines eg

```
scipy.sparse.spdiags([1.1,1.2,1.3],1,4,4).toarray()
```

returns

```
array([[ 0. ,  1.2,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.3,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

That is for positive diagonals it drops the first k data.  One might argue that there is some grand programming reason for this and that I just need to pad with zeros.  OK annoying as that may be, one can use scipy.sparse.diags which gives the correct result.  However this routine has a bug that can't be worked around

```
scipy.sparse.diags([1.1,1.2],0,(4,2)).toarray()
```

gives

```
array([[ 1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1.2],
       [ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ]])
```

nice, and

```
scipy.sparse.diags([1.1,1.2],-2,(4,2)).toarray()
```

gives

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1.2]])
```

but

```
scipy.sparse.diags([1.1,1.2],-1,(4,2)).toarray()
```

gives an error saying ValueError: Diagonal length (index 0: 2 at offset -1) does not agree with matrix size (4, 2).  Obviously the answer is

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1.2],
       [ 0. ,  0. ]])
```

and for extra random behaviour we have

```
scipy.sparse.diags([1.1],-1,(4,2)).toarray()
```

giving

```
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1.1],
       [ 0. ,  0. ]])
```

Anyone know if there is a function for constructing diagonal sparse matrices that actually works?

Comment: That does seem to be a bug in `scipy.sparse.diags`. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L63), we can see that the diagonal length calculation is `m, n = shape ... length = min(m + offset, n - offset)`, and that just isn't right. This deserves a bug report.

Comment: More of the code is in my answer.  I wonder if `length = min(m + k, n - k)` is the correct `length`.  It may be just coincidence that the `offset=-2` case works.

Comment: I recall a SO question that contrasted `spdiags` with a Matlab equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executive summary:  `spdiags` works correctly, even if the matrix input isn't the most intuitive.  `diags` has a bug that affects some offsets in rectangular matrices.  There is a bug fix on scipy github.

---

The example for `spdiags` is:

```
>>> data = array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
>>> diags = array([0,-1,2])
>>> spdiags(data, diags, 4, 4).todense()
matrix([[1, 0, 3, 0],
        [1, 2, 0, 4],
        [0, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 4]])
```

Note that the 3rd column of `data` always appears in the 3rd column of the sparse.  The other columns also line up.  But they are omitted where they 'fall off the edge'.

The input to this function is a matrix, while the input to `diags` is a ragged list.  The diagonals of the sparse matrix all have different numbers of values.  So the specification has to accomodate this in one or other.  `spdiags` does this by ignoring some values, `diags` by taking a list input.

The `sparse.diags([1.1,1.2],-1,(4,2))` error is puzzling.

the `spdiags` equivalent does work:

```
In [421]: sparse.spdiags([[1.1,1.2]],-1,4,2).A
Out[421]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1.2],
       [ 0. ,  0. ]])
```

The error is raised in this block of code:

```
for j, diagonal in enumerate(diagonals):
    offset = offsets[j]
    k = max(0, offset)
    length = min(m + offset, n - offset)
    if length <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Offset %d (index %d) out of bounds" % (offset, j))
    try:
        data_arr[j, k:k+length] = diagonal
    except ValueError:
        if len(diagonal) != length and len(diagonal) != 1:
            raise ValueError(
                "Diagonal length (index %d: %d at offset %d) does not "
                "agree with matrix size (%d, %d)." % (
                j, len(diagonal), offset, m, n))
        raise
```

The actual matrix constructor in the `diags` is:

```
dia_matrix((data_arr, offsets), shape=(m, n))
```

This is the same constructor that `spdiags` uses, but without any manipulation.

```
In [434]: sparse.dia_matrix(([[1.1,1.2]],-1),shape=(4,2)).A
Out[434]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1.1,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1.2],
       [ 0. ,  0. ]])
```

In `dia` format, the inputs are stored exactly as given by `spdiags` (complete with that matrix with extra values):

```
In [436]: M.data
Out[436]: array([[ 1.1,  1.2]])
In [437]: M.offsets
Out[437]: array([-1], dtype=int32)
```

---

As `@user2357112` points out, `length = min(m + offset, n - offset` is wrong, producing `3` in the test case.  Changing it to `length = min(m + k, n - k)` makes all cases for this (4,2) matrix work. But it fails with the transpose: `diags([1.1,1.2], 1, (2, 4))`

The correction, as of Oct 5, for this issue is:

https://github.com/pv/scipy-work/commit/529cbde47121c8ed87f74fa6445c05d71353eb6c

```
length = min(m + offset, n - offset, min(m,n))
```

With this fix, `diags([1.1,1.2], 1, (2, 4))` works.

Comment: Yeah, but check out the `scipy.sparse.diags([1.1,1.2],-1,(4,2)).toarray()` example. That one should work, but it's hitting an incorrect diagonal length calculation in the `diags` implementation.

Comment: Who wants to file the bug report, or at least search for existing ones? :)  I've contributed to `numpy`, but not `scipy` yet.

Comment: I never got around to creating a GitHub account, so I can't file the report. You might as well do it. I don't think changing `offset` to `k` fixes the bug, though. The problem should still occur with the transpose of the failing test case: `scipy.sparse.diags([1.1,1.2], 1, (2, 4)).toarray()`

Comment: I found a bug fix on the scipy github.

Comment: That's not quite the SciPy GitHub; that's one developer's private fork. [I found the pull request, though.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5313) It looks like the fix is going to go in.

Comment: Right.  I first found the issue on the main fork, and then just followed one of the links, and didn't pay close attention to where it took me.